# Chef HTTP request GET/POST

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am learning chef. I need some examples that calls http request GET/POST. If the request is GET, where do we get the content? I have read through the chef documentation but couldn't get enough on this. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're learning chef you've probably read all about cookbooks, recipes, and resources.  Chef is based on a desired state configuration where you declare the desired state in the form of resources which are grouped into recipes and cookbooks.  The chef-client brings your nodes into this declared desired state.  Resources are the base unit of desired state declaration.  So, you won't find resources which have "output" in the programming sense.  You will find resources that download to a file for example (i.e. remote_file).  Often times that's appropriate and no need to look further, but if you need to call remote services for programming/logic reasons, you'll typically see this done either in the form of [Custom Resources](https://docs.chef.io/custom_resources.html) that you author and call from your recipes.  Or in the form of helper functions defined as [Libraries](https://docs.chef.io/libraries.html) that you call from your resources and/or recipes.  Both offer the full power of Ruby to do whatever you want.  Libraries is probably the easiest place to start.  You'll be best served keeping your recipes as declarative of desired state as possible with programming conditionals pushed into Libraries and/or Resources.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have created cluster on server and I want to get its info using Chef http_request GET command. I am following the ruby script according to following script
[link](http://ideone.com/YRecuN)
Here what should be written in name field?

Comment: It's best not to think of this as a 'script'.  [https://docs.chef.io/resource_http_request.html](http_request) is a Chef resource.  http_request allows you to perform an http request operation as part of the recipe convergence.  The purpose of this resource is sending messages to remote systems - not retrieve data.  Per my previous reply - you'd be better of making an http call in a [Library](https://docs.chef.io/libraries.html_ method using [net http](https://apidock.com/ruby/Net/HTTP) and calling it from your recipe and returning the data to your recipe.